# WebdriverIO: How to fix error "unknown error: cannot get automation extension"?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

### Current setup:

- [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/)
- Using [wdio-selenium-standalone-service](https://github.com/webdriverio/wdio-selenium-standalone-service/)

> **Note:**
>
> The comments mentioning this as a duplicate are for when you're maintaining your own chromedriver and selenium installation, but if you use `wdio-selenium-standalone-service` those "duplicate" questions/solutions don't help. Hopefully this gives context

We have a major problem running automated UI tests as of today:

```
[13:35:36]      Failed to take screenshot on reject:     {"message":"unknown error: cannot get automation extension\nfrom unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html","type":"RuntimeError","seleniumStack":{"status":13,"type":"UnknownError","message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","orgStatusMessage":"unknown error: cannot get automation extension\nfrom unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html\n  (Session info: chrome= ... (1233 more bytes)"}}
F..------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome #0-0] Session ID: c58395b3-9e09-4d67-987d-f385bca117cc
[chrome #0-0] Spec: C:\Development\step_definitionswebsite-logo.feature
[chrome #0-0] Running: chrome
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0]   As a tester I need to verify some home page elements
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0]   Company logo has a valid alternative text
[chrome #0-0]       1) I open the homepage
[chrome #0-0]       - I check the logo text
[chrome #0-0]       - I get a logo text matching "Logo"
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0] 2 pending (30s)
[chrome #0-0] 1 failing
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0] 1) Company logo has a valid alternative text9 I open the homepage:
[chrome #0-0] unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
[chrome #0-0] Error: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
[chrome #0-0]     at Object.setViewportSize (C:\Development\node_modules\wdio-sync\build\index.js:330:27)
[chrome #0-0]     at Page.open (C:\Development\lib\page-objects\page.js:26:21)
[chrome #0-0]     at customWorld.<anonymous> (C:\Development\ui-tests\cucumber\step_definitions\ui-given.js:11:14)
[chrome #0-0]     at C:\Development\node_modules\wdio-sync\build\index.js:578:26
[chrome #0-0]     at Promise.F (C:\Development\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\_export.js:35:28)
[chrome #0-0]     at customWorld.executeSync (C:\Development\node_modules\wdio-sync\build\index.js:576:12)
[chrome #0-0]     at C:\Development\node_modules\wdio-sync\build\index.js:191:29
[chrome #0-0]     from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
[chrome #0-0]     at windowHandleSize([object Object]) - C:\Development\node_modules\webdriverio\build\lib\commands\setViewportSize.js:60:68
[chrome #0-0]     at setViewportSize([object Object], false) -     at C:\Development\\node_modules\wdio-sync\build\at Object.wait (C:\Development\\node_modules\fibers\future.js:449:15)
```

We use this line in our wdio.conf.js:

```
services: ['selenium-standalone']
```

And this is our packages.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "assign-deep": "^0.4.5",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^3.17.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.1.1",
    "fs-extra": "^2.0.0",
    "graceful": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cucumber": "0.0.22",
    "gulp-mocha": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-webdriver": "^2.0.3",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.3",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha-each": "^1.0.3",
    "mocha-teamcity-reporter": "^1.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "teamcity-properties": "^1.1.0",
    "url-join": "^1.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "wdio-cucumber-framework": "^0.2.16",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.9",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.8",
    "wdio-spec-reporter": "0.0.5",
    "wdio-teamcity-reporter": "^1.1.1",
    "webdriverio": "^4.6.2",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.16.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Got the latest npm modules for wdio-related pieces. It fails consistently for any UI tests (mocha and cucumber and we use both at the moment). We have not tried downgrading Chrome but it might be a necessity soon.

> **Note**
>
> 1. credits to user `miroslawmajka` on github
> 2. I've similar issues, so I'm using their bug description and solution

Comment: Googled the error... first result was the answer.

Comment: @JeffC all of us get different (personalized) results for the same query 

Comment: Great... you telling me you googled `unknown error: cannot get automation extension` and didn't see the above link on the first results page?

Comment: @JeffC It's easy to be condescending on Internet but is not helpful. Link you've listed doesn't apply to `webdriverio` using `selenium-standalone`

Comment: Yet the solution is the same... update chromedriver. It just gets old/frustrating having people ask questions but when you google the exact error message, the answer is found on page 1.

Comment: @JeffC I understand where you're coming from. This scenario is different. in this scenario, you wouldn't update chromedriver manually, but add the JSON in the config file so that `selenium-standalone` would do the job for you. Hope you see that this is different

Answer (score 1):

## Solution: update chromedriver by adding this JSON to config file

### 1. The following is the configuration for just chromedriver

For those who are interested in using the **selenium-standalone** service with **WebdriverIO** we have modified our **wdio.conf.js** to use the following statements:

```
{
    services: ['selenium-standalone'],
    seleniumLogs: './context/selenium-logs',
    seleniumArgs: {
        drivers: {
            chrome: {
                version: 2.28,
                baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
            }
        }
    },
    seleniumInstallArgs: {
        drivers: {
            chrome: {
                version: 2.28,
                baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that works with our setup with the latest version of Chrome. Thank you for the tip but we had to go about it a different way as we are using **wdio-selenium-standalone-service** for managing Selenium.

### 2. This is the configuration for all browsers

```
services: ['selenium-standalone'],
seleniumLogs: './context/selenium-logs',
seleniumArgs: {
    drivers: {
        // chrome: {
        //     version: 2.28,
        //     baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
        // },
        chrome: {
            // check for more recent versions of chrome driver here:
            // http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
            version: '2.33',
            //arch: process.arch,
            baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
        },
        ie: {
            // check for more recent versions of internet explorer driver here:
            // http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
            version: '3.6.0',
            //arch: 'ia32',
            baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com'
        },
        firefox: {
            // check for more recent versions of gecko  driver here:
            // https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
            version: '0.19.0',
            //arch: process.arch,
            baseURL: 'https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download'
        }
    }
},
seleniumInstallArgs: {
    drivers: {
        // chrome: {
        //     version: 2.28,
        //     baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
        // },
        chrome: {
            // check for more recent versions of chrome driver here:
            // http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
            version: '2.33',
            //arch: process.arch,
            baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
        },
        ie: {
            // check for more recent versions of internet explorer driver here:
            // http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
            version: '3.6.0',
            //arch: 'ia32',
            baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com'
        },
        firefox: {
            // check for more recent versions of gecko  driver here:
            // https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
            version: '0.19.0',
            //arch: process.arch,
            baseURL: 'https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dheeraj!